# How can I see the graph of my training results in yolov4 if my colab stopped running when it finished in train?

Tags: graph, charts, google-colaboratory, yolov4

I have train with yolov4 using Google Colab. But, when it finished, my Colab stopped running and I cannot see the charts of my training results. Is there any ways to see the graphs? Thanks.

I follow this code for training: https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/YOLOv4-Cloud-Tutorial

Comment: Which code/github repo did you follow for training? Please be more specific

Comment: sorry, I follow this code https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/YOLOv4-Cloud-Tutorial

Comment: Since the code is using `https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet` and is built with OpenCV enabled, you should have a file called `chart.png` in the root directory (darknet) that shows the training loss and the mAP. But I suppose it's been a while since the session has been closed and you may not have any files in the colab session anymore. You can check for this the next time you train and after it finishes evaluation (I think after 1000 iterations are reached)

Comment: so, I must train again? ok thanks for the answer ^^